# Styling hooks for the find/replace dialog

Tags: ace-editor

Is there a built in way to theme/style the find/replace dialog? If not, are the style classes stable / am I safe overriding the style rules for them?

Answer (score 0):

Find/replace dialog is `.ace_search` so that's not too hard to style.

The implementation in general is isolated in `ext-searchbox.js`.